# Ubuntu EFI not visible after Win10 update

Tags: boot-repair

I had a working Ubuntu EFI on a separate SSD. Updated Win10 and can no longer see the EFI. Might have been something on my end. Would I just create another Ubuntu EFI USB so I can transfer the USB EFI to my SSD?

I can't remember the version it was, but it was the latest LTS version.

Comment: You cannot really transfer an ESP from one to another. It has UUIDs & GUIDs. While boot files may be same, if full install, configuration files are different. Boot Repair -Also handles LVM, GPT, separate /boot and UEFI dual boot, only use ppa download into Ubuntu live installer.
Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you!